# finding database.ini file in Windows

Tags: python, windows, postgresql

I want to connect to the Postgresql database using Python in Windows. This is the function I have written:

```
def config(filename='', section='postgresql'):
# create a parser
parser = ConfigParser()
# read config file
parser.read(filename)
# get section, default to postgresql
db = {}
if parser.has_section(section):
    params = parser.items(section)
    for param in params:
        db[param[0]] = param[1]
else:
    raise Exception('section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))
return db
```

I have read that I should put "database.ini" in front of "filename". However, it gives me the following message:

```
section postgresql not found in the database.ini file
```

Where should I find the "database.ini" in Windows?

Comment: This makes no sense.  What library are you using to try to connect? Where is `database.ini` coming from? I see nothing in this code that will result in a connection. What is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same code and had the same issue. I was able to resolve the issue by moving all of my code up one folder level.

I am working in vscode on Windows 10. My python source code was located in a nested folder like c:\repos\myProject\myProject. I moved everything up to c:\repos\myProject and then it worked fine.

I can't explain why that has solved the problem but it has in my case. Perhaps it's related to the location of the virtual env or **pycache**

Also to answer your question about database.ini - you create that file yourself and can put it in the same relative path. Useful resource [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/)

Anyway I can confirm your code definitely works on Windows 10.